# Pandas: Count consecutive duplicates (not with loop) and add column to original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
value = [1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(value)

df['count'] = [2,2,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,2,2,1]
```

I want to generate 'count' column but not with loop,because the original data is huge.

Is there a function or other efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column filled by `count`s with helper `Series` created by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)d column with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) and add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for consecutive groups:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df[0].ne(df[0].shift()).cumsum())[0].transform('size')
print (df)
    0  count
0   1      2
1   1      2
2   2      3
3   2      3
4   2      3
5   1      1
6   2      3
7   2      3
8   2      3
9   3      2
10  3      2
11  4      1
```